# Python Retrieve values from List in a Specific order

Tags: python, json, recursion, postfix-notation

I have a Python program to get data from a JSON file and then store it into a list in post fix order. However now, I am trying to put the data into a new list which is in readable math notation. The issue is that I know that I need to find the first operator and then find the previous two numbers - I can do that for the first set however the recursion past that point is not working and I can't figure out why!

```
   testList = [None] * len(valueList)
global testListCounter
testListCounter = 0

def _solveProblem(i, testListCounter): 
    for i in range (len(typeList)):
        if typeList[i] == "operation":
            testList[testListCounter +1 ] = valueList[i]
            _findLeftInteger(i)
            i = i + 3
           # _findRightInteger(i)
            testListCounter = testListCounter + 3
    return _solveProblem(i+1, testListCounter)



def _findLeftInteger(opPos):
    for i in range(opPos, 0, -1):
        if typeList[i-1] == ("constant") or typeList[i-1] == ("cell"):
            testList[testListCounter] = valueList[opPos-1]
            _findRightInteger(i-1)

def _findRightInteger(opPos):
    for i in range(opPos, 0, -1):
        if typeList[i-1] == ("constant") or typeList[i-1] == ("cell"):
            testList[testListCounter+2] = valueList[opPos-1]


_solveProblem(0, testListCounter)
print (testList)
```

valueList contains:

```
 ['2', '90', '/', 'pi', '100', 13604.5, '20', '90', '/', '*', '+', '100', '+', '+
', '+']
```

typeList contains:

```
['constant', 'constant', 'operation', 'function', 'constant', 'cell', 'constant'
, 'constant', 'operation', 'operation', 'operation', 'constant', 'operation', 'o
peration', 'operation']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider moving to a stack-based approach - push the operands onto an operand stack as you encounter them.  Every time you encounter an operator, pop the appropriate number of operands off the operand stack (it's always 2 in your example, sine I only see binary operators) - evaluate the expression and push the result back onto the operand stack.  The algorithm is spelled out in more detail here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm

Attempting to do this with a positional index-based approach can get pretty awkward - since you have operators that have different levels of precedence, your logic would also have to handle how to skip over operands that have already been "consumed".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a stack. Each numeric token you encounter gets pushed on the stack. When you encounter an operator token, you pop two tokens from the stack and transform that into an infix expression. Then you push back the resulting expression back onto the stack.

e.g. on input

1, 2, 3, +, +

You push 1, 2 and 3, so your stack becomes

[1, 2, 3]

you encounter +, so you pop 2 and 3 and create an infix expression

[1, (2+3)]

You encounter +, so you pop the two elements and create an infix expression

[(1+(2+3))]